# How to display all employees under each manager

Tags: c#, sql

I have 2 tables:

> **Mrg**: UserID || UserID_Mrg || Status

and

> **User**: UserID || Name

I want to display all employees (UserID) under each Manager (UserID_Mrg)

example:

`UserID_Mrg = 12`

So display all UserID with UserID_Mrg = 12

so far I could just display the users Information an their Manager:

C#:

```
private void BindGridView()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
                     @"SELECT tbl_user.Name, tbl_mrg.UserID_Mrg
                       FROM   tbl_mrg 
                       INNER JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_mrg.UserID = tbl_user.UserID 
                       WHERE  ((tbl_mag.user_ID = @UserID))
                       ORDER BY     tbl_user.Name", con))
        {
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserID", SessionHelper.UserID));
            adapter.Fill(Data2);
            GridView2.DataSource = Data2;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server">
    <Columns>      
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Mrg" HeaderText="Manager" SortExpression="Manager" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change the where condition

```
SELECT tbl_user.Name As EmployeeName,tbl_user.UserID  as EmployeeId tbl_mrg.UserID_Mrg as ManagerId
         FROM   tbl_mrg 
         INNER JOIN tbl_user ON tbl_mrg.UserID = tbl_user.UserID 
         WHERE  ((tbl_mag.UserID_Mrg = @UserID)
```

As you want to get all the users under a manager, so inner join is fine and a bit change in where condition will provide you the desired result